# Java SWT Link widget - How can I remove the hyperlink underline?

Tags: java, swt, hyperlink, underline

I knew that we can use:

```
setText("<a> href="url"> Link </a>");
```

to set up a link.
But the output of this is underlined.

I want to have a link that is not underlined,
so I tried

```
setText(<a> href="url" style="text-decoration: none" Link </a>);
```

But it still doesnt work.
Any HELP?

Answer (score 5):

Well, you cannot remove the underline. It is drawn internally with the help of the TextLayout class and there is no way to influence the behavior. By the way the HTML code for the text widget is only used internally for parsing. There is actually no HTML support for the Link widget. This is why the style attribute doesn't work. You can however use the StyledText widget for more advanced text layout.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to Tobias Willig's answer, if your are working with JFace and Forms then you can use `org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Hyperlink` and its `setUnderlined()`. You can see a working example here: [Custom Components](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/CustomComponents.htm)

Comment: Just tried, I dont think its suitable as what I am doing with Link Widget now is that I can just create a single Link and displays multiple HyperLinks within normal text at the same time.

Comment: @user2215977 - It is just an alternative approach which is available with appropriate API for hiding underlines.